# Convert CSV to PNG with matplotlib Issue

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I am trying to create a PNG image with some CSV data but I am getting an error related to the date column (meanwhile converted to list).  The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/user1/Desktop/Py/AgentsStatus/testGraph.py", line 57, in <module>
    plt.plot(dateCol,okCol,linewidth=5)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3154, in plot
    ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1812, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1425, in plot
    self.add_line(line)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 1708, in add_line
    self._update_line_limits(line)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 1730, in _update_line_limits
    path = line.get_path()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 925, in get_path
    self.recache()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 612, in recache
    x = np.asarray(xconv, np.float_)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 482, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '11-04-2016'
```

CSV contains:

```
11-04-2016;37180;6;23852
18-04-2016;37341;9;24105
25-04-2016;37075;18;23788
```

My code is:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

path = 'C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\Py\\AgentsStatus\\data.csv'

with open (path) as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')

    dateCol = [] # date list

    for row in readCSV:
        if row:
            date0 = row[0]
            dateCol.append(date0)

with open (path) as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')

    okCol = [] # all agents list

    for row in readCSV:
        if row:
            ok0 = row[1]
            okCol.append(ok0)


with open (path) as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')

    heaCol = [] # healthy list




from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style

style.use('ggplot')


# can plot specifically, after just showing the defaults:
plt.plot(dateCol,okCol,linewidth=5)
plt.plot(dateCol,heaCol,linewidth=5)

plt.title('Epic Info')
plt.ylabel('Y axis')
plt.xlabel('X axis')

plt.show()
```

My goal is to create something like below:

[image]

Could you give me please some tips of what am I doing wrong? I think my problem mitght be that I am not setting the List dateCol as the Index for the graph (to not plot it). Could you please help me on that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `I am getting an error related to the date column` - What is the error?

Comment: Hello, its ValueError: could not convert string to float: '11-04-2016'

Comment: That's an important piece of information - include the *entire traceback* in your question.

Comment: Already updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: Your problem may go a little deeper than just that error. Have you looked at this recipe? http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html

Comment: The *entire traceback* please. From the line `Traceback (most recent call last):`  down to the line you posted. **All of it is important**

Comment: More details of the error added. Thank you @That1Guy

Comment: @VinceWest the date in this case is static.. already populated in the CSV as column. JUst need to be pulled to the graph same way as the rest of the data. thank you

Comment: I think my problem is that I am not setting the List dateCol as the Index for the graph (to not plot it). Could you please help me on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For stuff like this Pandas is unbeatable:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pandas.read_csv('sampledata.csv', delimiter=';', 
                     index_col=0, 
                     parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True, 
                     names=['date','a','b','c'])
df.plot()

plt.savefig('sampledata.png')
```

Results in

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It's what I was looking for. Just one question, where can I find information to configure for example colors of lines, write dates in vertical (for bigger sets of data), etc..?

Comment: [The docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) are pretty good.